# Need to run .jar file having .sh file on desktop for all PC's.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, gnome-terminal

i'm running a .Jar file User Interface which include script from Desktop of PC by following code in netbeans.

String[] pc1 = {"gnome-terminal","-e","/home/noman-i7/Desktop/connect/pc1.sh"};

my code include [user name], i can't change it every time to be used for different PC's having different usernames.

need a tip or code to make it run on every PC by placing the Shell script on desktop or any other specific location.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for everyone having execution right on it, on unix clone systems /usr/local/bin  is typically the place to copy the script to.

Comment: Copied folders to usr/local/bin as root user , butwhen i run the code it says, 

There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
,Failed to execute child process "/usr/local/bin/connect/pc1.sh" (Permission Denied).

is there any othere folder that do not require permission? 
OR
i will need to make my interface to be run as root user?

Comment: It's not usual to make directories under the bin/ directories, all files dwell directly under  them... but it's not your problem.

You should run ls -ld /usr/local/bin/connect and ls -l /usr/local/bin/connect/* and show the result.

Comment: Sandor ; when i click the option to run the shell script form usr/local/bin _ the terminal flashes and nothing else is happening_my code is NOW for Interface button is ____
String[] pc1 = {"gnome-terminal","-e","ls -l /usr/local/bin/connect/pc1.sh"};
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pc1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }

Comment: I understand what's happening and would like to investigate why. The 2 ls commands above would support that.

Comment: WORKED BY Using ls As Follow 
"gnome-terminal", "-x", "bash", "-c", "ls; '/usr/local/bin/connect/pc1.sh'; read"};
--
Will ask if anything else happens Next :D :p 
Thanks.